# How do I retain carriage returns while moving data from a web service into Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, web-services, xaml

My carriage returns are lost when inserted into Sql Server 2005 as an NVarChar parameter coming from a web service. I know the carriage returns exist in the web service fields because when I bind the same data to a WPF ComboBox I see returns occurring in the proper locations.

The code looks something like this:

```
string insertSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable (FieldWithCrLf,...) VALUES (@FieldWithCrLf,...)";

dbConn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@insertSQL, dbConn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldWithCrLf", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
        ...
    }

foreach (WebServiceRecord rec in allDataFromWebService)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@FieldWithCrLfr"].Value = rec.FieldWithCrLfFromWebService;
        ...
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

**How can I retain the carriage return / line feeds so they are stored in my Sql Server fields?**

Comment: maybe the CR/LF are being stored, but you need to replace them with a <BR> so they show properly on the web page?

Comment: I'm building a WPF app, not a web page. But you raise a good point. How can I determine if my NVarChar fields contain CR/LFs? I assumed that would be apparent once I bound the data to WPF controls.

Comment: How are you confirming that the CR/LFs are not in the database?

Comment: When bound to WPF Toolkit RichTextBox's they aren't there. What's the best way to confirm CR/LFs are in (or not in) the database?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, Query window, enter `SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [TableName]` where [ColumnName] and [TableName] describe where the data is stored.  From Query menu, select Results To -> Results to Text (ctrl-T), and then run.  You should see multi-line output

Comment: Wow, they are there! My bad. Thanks. I've got to check my assumptions. I assumed they weren't there because they didn't show in my app. How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: Did you check whether there are any CR in the returned `rec.FieldWithCrLfFromWebService`? I mean, you believe that they _should_ be there but have you confirmed it (carefully)? I mean not depending on the debugger or anything like that.

Comment: @bobs: you should add an answer from your comment, then the OP can accept it (and I can upvote it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should see if the CR/LFs are in the database.

In the SQL Server Management Studio, Query window, enter

```
SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [TableName]
```

where [ColumnName] and [TableName] describe where the data is stored.

From the Query menu, select Results To -> Results to Text (ctrl-T), and then run. You should see multi-line output.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you'd look for in the database.

But you might try xml:space="preserve" in your wpf textblock.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed my REAL problem. Now the CrLf's show as needed. Too bad I can't mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: In a WPF Textbox you can allow users to add CrLf's with the Enter key by setting AcceptsReturn="True". Similarly to allow tabs set AcceptsTab="True". See: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/10/26/wpf-textbox-some-more-improvements-and-features.aspx